# Scaffold DbContext The string argument 'sql' cannot be empty

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, scaffolding

This is my database table

```
CREATE TABLE `File` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extension` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `path` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The command I use to generate the models:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "server=..;user id=..;password=..;database=..;sslmode=none;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -f
```

The error I get:

```
System.ArgumentException: The string argument 'sql' cannot be empty.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NullButNotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions.HasComputedColumnSql(PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder, String sql)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitColumn(EntityTypeBuilder builder, ColumnModel column)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitColumns(EntityTypeBuilder builder, ICollection`1 columns)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTable(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, TableModel table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ICollection`1 tables)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.CreateFromDatabaseModel(DatabaseModel databaseModel)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MySQLScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(String connectionString, TableSelectionSet tableSelectionSet)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GetMetadataModel(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineeringGenerator.GenerateAsync(ReverseEngineeringConfiguration configuration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContextAsync(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<ScaffoldContextImpl>d__22.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32& length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The string argument 'sql' cannot be empty.
```

It says the sql argument cannot be empty, but I don't use 'sql' anywhere. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've "fixed" the problem by using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` instead of `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`